# Ignore timezone when creating Date from numeric values

Tags: javascript, datetime

Simple example:

```
new Date(2018,0,1,0,0,0,0)
```

Produces `2017-12-31T23:00:00.000Z` where I'm at (GMT+1). I am creating dates from string values in the following format:

```
YYYYMMDD HHmm
20170326 0135
```

These come from weather data at ftp://ftp.ncdc.noaa.gov/pub/data/uscrn/products/subhourly01/2017/. Now I tried to workaround the timeout issue by adding one to hours, eg.: `new Date(2018,0,1,0+1,0,0,0)`->`2018-01-01T00:00:00.000Z`

But that fails if you want to make date near midnight, since adding 1 to 23:30, for example, creates 24:30 which is invalid value. The result will be midnight the same day, not 1'o clock the next day:

```
new Date(2018,0,1,23+1,30,0,0)
2018-01-01T23:30:00.000Z
```

Also, for some reason, `Date` substracts 2 hours from some times:

```
new Date(2017, 2, 26, 3, 0, 0, 0);
2017-03-26T01:00:00.000Z
```

So this question is - how do I create date **ignoring timezones** so that I can create it from local datetime strings.

Comment: You can't really "ignore timezones" when creating timezone aware objects (the only kind of date objects native to Javascript). What timezones *are* those timestamps in…?

Comment: how does the `23+1` doesn't work for you? because for me works also with `23+3`. It increases the day by one when I do that.

Comment: @deceze I don't know, but I want to display them the way they are. Maybe I can't *ignore* timezones. So how do I tell the Date object that the input is in GMT+0?

Comment: maybe this can help you https://codepen.io/anon/pen/djXYjN?editors=1111

Comment: no upvotes and only 200 views after 2 years? really? how comes nobody else is having these issues?! you should probably add a bunch of keywords into the question, I was about to open my own question after googling and not finding anything. "wrong day" "wrong hour" "wrong timezone" or so. As well: include the solution for strings e.g. `var mydate = new Date('2020-11-23');` will be 22st of november etc as well

Comment: @Toskan Answers also influence SEO. If you have more extended answer than the one that I have accepted and that covers the string date problem, please add it as it may help more people.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Date.UTC](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/UTC) function which returns UTC timestamp:

```
new Date(Date.UTC(2018, 0, 1, 23, 30, 0, 0))
```

By the way, 24:30 is completely valid for the JS date. It will correctly overflow to the next day.

Answer (score 1):

the accepted answer is correct. But helpful in many cases might be a little info.

First I want to say, if I give `2020-02-02` I dont request conversions - but that is exactly what `new Date()` starts doing. And not consistently.

```js
var date1 = new Date('2020-02-02'); //clearly assumes input is UTC!
console.error(date1.toString()); //for me, not 2020-02-02
console.error(date1.toUTCString()); //2020-02-02


var date1 = new Date('2020-02-02 13:00:00'); //clearly assumes LOCAL time 
console.error(date1.toString()); //correct for me
console.error(date1.toUTCString()); //incorrect, e.g. wrong hour
```

we *always* want to work with UTC unless you specifically want to start doing conversions to local time. But if you want to do that, you will know that. Usually you don't.

So always work with the UTC functions of `Date` like `date.getUTCMonth()` BUT: the date you feed it, needs to be UTC as well. Otherwise the conversion pit of doom starts.

```js
   function getDateUTC(str) {
        function getUTCDate(myDateStr){
            if(myDateStr.length <= 10){
                //const date = new Date(myDateStr); //is already assuming UTC, smart - but for browser compatibility we will add time string none the less
                const date = new Date(myDateStr.trim() + 'T00:00:00Z');
                return date;
            }else{
                throw "only date strings, not date time";
            }
        }

        function getUTCDatetime(myDateStr){
            if(myDateStr.length <= 10){
                throw "only date TIME strings, not date only";
            }else{
                return new Date(myDateStr.trim() +'Z'); //this assumes no time zone is part of the date string. Z indicates UTC time zone
            }
        }  
        
        let rv = '';
        
        if(str && str.length){
            if(str.length <= 10){
                rv = getUTCDate(str);
            }else if(str.length > 10){
                rv = getUTCDatetime(str);
            } 
        }else{
            rv = '';
        }
        return rv;
    }

console.info(getDateUTC('2020-02-02').toUTCString());

var mydateee2 = getDateUTC('2020-02-02 02:02:02');
console.info(mydateee2.toUTCString());

// you are free to use all UTC functions on date e.g.
console.info(mydateee2.getUTCHours())
console.info('all is good now if you use UTC functions')
```